# How to build single angular module and deploy it separately?

Tags: angular, bazel, modularity, docker-image

We have a big angular application containing 1000 modules. While deploying application we have to deploy the whole app from dist this approach is not good for any large application.
**Is there any way to build a specified module from application and deploy it separately**. Like we have CM and PM separate two modules now I want to build CM and deploy it's generated stuff on the server.
we use bazel to build separate module but deployment is very hard with @bazel.

Comment: I have the same question, I still haven’t found solution.

Comment: I found **single-spa** can do this! but I not sure it's stable.

Comment: there is lot of problems with single-spa in terms of seperate deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution and was heard about micro frontend where we can deploy each module independently. I found this medium article.

https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-implement-micro-frontend-architecture-with-angular-e6828a0a049c

And you can check this Nx freamwork as well.
https://nx.dev/getting-started/angular-standalone-tutorial.

https://nx.dev/recipes/adopting-nx/migration-angular#transforming-an-angular-cli-workspace-to-an-nx-workspace

Hope this helps :)
And if you already got something better than this, please let me know as well :)

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question at that time it was experimental. now many libraries claim this like nx and others but this is like a big goal there are many aspect we need to understand that as well. very soon I'm going to write article on that.
I will update here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35188998)